# Remove from datatable after callback is finished

Tags: javascript

I have a datatable, a checkbox on each table, and a button that will trigger my operation on that row. I would like to remove that row when my operation is done.

```
for (i = 0; i < checkedBoxes.length; i++) {
    var chk = checkedBoxes[i];
    var tdef = chk.closest("tr").querySelectorAll('td');
    var myThing = tdef[1].innerHTML;

    service.doSomething(myThing, function (result) {
        service.doSomethingElse();

        // I would like to remove this row once I'm done with this row
        //browseDataTable.row($(chk).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
    });
}
```

I know that I'm not supposed to remove that row as I'm looping through it. So I'm planning to just collect the index of each row, and when everything is finished, I can remove it, like this:

```
var myArr = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < checkedBoxes.length; i++) {
    service.doSomething(myThing, function (result) {
        service.doSomethingElse();

        myArr.push(i);
    })  // Chrome said 'then' is undefined, so how do I chain callback here?
    .then(function () {
        // Remove all rows at index in myArr
    });
}
```

The service isn't async service, it's an ASMX service.

Answer (score 0):

You are using your service both like a function with a callback *and* a Promise. So which is it? Does it take a callback, or does it return a Promise?

It looks like it does not return a Promise, because you are trying to chain `.then()` and it's undefined.

`The service isn't async` then why are you giving it a callback and trying to chain a `.then()`, if it's synchronous?

Anyway, one easy way to solve your issue is to use `let`, which will create a scope for every loop.

Currently :

```
for (i = 0; i < checkedBoxes.length; i++) { // i is a global (window) variable, that's bad
    service.doSomething(myThing, function (result) {
        service.doSomethingElse();
        myArr.push(i); // i will always be checkboxes.length
    })
}
```

By using let :

```
for (let i = 0; i < checkedBoxes.length; i++) { // i is in the local scope
    service.doSomething(myThing, function (result) {
        service.doSomethingElse();
        myArr.push(i); // the value of i will be different (correct) each time
    })
}
```

Comment: You're right, it's synchronous, so it doesn't take Promise. I just put it there to make it clear what I wanted to do, which is do another operation after the callback happened. But I have no idea how to do that - remove all selected rows after I have called the service.

Comment: Oh, you gave me a diff idea on how to solve my problem with 'let'. Thanks!